# filter list to get unique and latest items

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

What's is the best way to get only unique and latest items from the list?
One method that I come up with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import date

Event = namedtuple('Event', ('id', 'type', 'date'))

event_1 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=date(2020, 1, 5))
event_2 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=date(2020, 1, 10))
event_3 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=date(2020, 1, 8))

event_4 = Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=date(2020, 1, 9))
event_5 = Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=date(2020, 1, 15))


data = [event_1, event_2, event_3, event_4, event_5]


grouped = groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type, -e.date)), key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type))

unique_latest = [next(item[1]) for item in grouped]
```

So the outcome should be: `unique_latest = [event_2, event_5]`.

So I group by uniqueness criteria (id, type) and take first item of each group.

But this approach does not guarantee that first item is the latest within its group.

Tried to do `sorted(data, key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type, -e.date))`, but python does not allow `-e.date`.

Comment: `-e.date` is indeed invalid, but `d0-e.date` is not, where `d0` is any fixed date (e.g., today, or `date(1970,1,1)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datetime` objects rather than `date`, you can use [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.datetime.timestamp) to convert the values to a float that can then be negated for sorting:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime

Event = namedtuple('Event', ('id', 'type', 'date'))

event_1 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=datetime(2020, 1, 5))
event_2 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=datetime(2020, 1, 10))
event_3 = Event(id=1, type='income', date=datetime(2020, 1, 8))

event_4 = Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=datetime(2020, 1, 9))
event_5 = Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=datetime(2020, 1, 15))


data = [event_1, event_2, event_3, event_4, event_5]


grouped = groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type, -e.date.timestamp())), key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type))

unique_latest = [next(item[1]) for item in grouped]

print(unique_latest)
```

Output:

```py
[
 Event(id=1, type='income', date=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 10, 0, 0)),
 Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 15, 0, 0))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only because negation (unary minus) is undefined for `datetime`.

Subtract the date from a greater date (say, next year), and sort using the `timedelta` result.

```
grouped = groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type,
                            date(2021, 12, 31) - e.date)),
                         key=lambda e: (e.id, e.type))
```

Result:

```
[Event(id=1, type='income', date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 10)),
 Event(id=2, type='outcome', date=datetime.date(2020, 1, 15))]
```

Comment: You can subtract from any date, not necessarily a greater date. Negative timedeltas are legal.

Comment: Correct -- I do it for simpler debugging ... just a habit.